# No module named cv2 in only one jupyter notebook

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook

Before someone says that this is a repeated question and I should just install it, hear my case:

I am running a jupyter notebook from a conda environment in which opencv is *already installed*

I have had no problem using opencv so far in this environment.

I have downloaded a jupyter notebook, I have also created my own.
In my own newly created notebook I put

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
#%matplotlib qt
%matplotlib inline
```

it runs without problems.
Then I open the other notebook (which is situated in the same directory as the previous one)
and I do

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib qt
```

and I get

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-b35e53327fbb> in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 import cv2
      3 import glob
      4 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      5 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'qt')

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

Why? It was running in the other notebook!

Answer (score 0):

See if both notebooks are running in the same virtual environment.

You can type `conda activate <env_name>` before running the notebook with `jupyter notebook` command.